# Using Population Statistics to Predict future Population Statistics: General or Specific Demographic Groups?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, prediction

I apologize in advance if I don't use the right terminology.

#### Problem to Solve:

I want to predict the voter turnout behavior of Black, Male, Non-latinos for Springfield in the upcoming election.

#### Data Sources:

I currently have access to historical voter turnout rates for

1. Black, Male, Non-latinos as a single population Springfield.
2. Blacks, Males, and Non-Latinos as separate populations in Springfield.

#### Question:

**Which data do I used to predict the upcoming voter turnout behavior?**

My gut tells me that these two approaches would certainly not lead to the same prediction, though I lack the education to explain why.

Comment: You probably be interested in Nate Silvers' work e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nate_Silver#FiveThirtyEight.27s_election_forecasts

Comment: @Tim, I have the book, but am curious if you know a source that would read more like a "Methods" section from a scholarly paper?